# Correct Change python program

Tags: python-3.x

I am supposed to

> Design and write a Python program that gives exact change for an item purchased with $5 or less. Use a float data type to represent money (You may want to multiply this number by 100 so that you get an integer for your calculation, such that $5.00 represents 500 cents, $2.35 represents 235 cents, etc.)

Below is my code:

```
amount = float(input('Enter item cost: '))
tender = float(input('Enter amount tendered: '))

change = int((tender - amount)*100)
dollars = change // 100
change = change % 100
quarters = change // 25
change = change % 25
dimes = change // 10
change = change % 10
nickels = change // 5
change = change % 5
pennies = change
#output
print('Dollar bills:', dollars)
print('Quarters:', quarters)
print('Dimes:', dimes)
print('Nickels:', nickels)
print('Pennies:', pennies)
```

An expected output for an item that costs $2.71 when the amount tendered is $5.00, would be:

```
Dollars: 2 
Quarters: 0 
Dimes: 2 
Nickels:1 
Pennies:4
```

but my output is giving me:

Enter item cost: 2.71
Enter amount tendered: 5.00

```
Dollars: 2 
Quarters: 1 
Dimes: 0 
Nickels: 0 
Pennies: 4
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: What debugging steps have you taken? Is the change value correct after each action you take?

Comment: 1. Is this homework? 2. that is the correct change isn’t it?

Comment: Note: 2 dimes and 1 nickel (first output)  is the same as one quarter (second output)... So,  does the output have to match _exactly_?

Comment: The output is correct. Does the assignment specifically ask for the quarters to be skipped?